# Jest - How to get coverage for mocked classes and implementations

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, code-coverage, jestjs

I'm currently working on a project where I'm using Jest for unit testing and code coverage.

Everything is working fine, except coverage for mocked classes/methods. I don't seem to get the desired coverage results. I've tried to find something in the Jest docs and searched online for an answer, but I can't seem to find anything about it.

The thing is that when I use a mocked implementation (for example `./services/__mocks__/UserService.js`), the actual implementation (`./services/UserService.js`) results in having 0% coverage. This is a logical outcome, since the implementation is overwritten by the mock.

I can get around this by using `/* istanbul ignore next */` on every method in the actual service or simply add the actual services to the `coveragePathIgnorePatterns` property in the Jest setup file and let it generate coverage for all mocked classes instead, but I wonder if there is any way to have Jest use the mocked implementation automatically for generating coverage results.

What is the way to go for mocked classes/functions and code coverage?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Typically a service like `UserService.js` will be mocked in the unit tests for code that depends on it, but will also have its own unit tests that ensure it works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in documentation says [for manual mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks), you'll use `./services/__mocks__/UserService.js` only if you explicitly called something like `jest.mock('./services/UserService');`.

If you want to write tests for `./services/UserService`, be convinced you don't use `jest.mock('./services/UserService');` before this tests.

Comment: Within OP's description, they mention: "Everything is working fine, except coverage for mocked classes/methods"

I personally am curious how I can mock a method (e.g. with jest.fn() ) but then have jest not feel the need to tell me that I'm missing coverage for that method)

I have a method in a Vue component that handles an event which I'm already testing for sufficiently, and I feel that adding another unit test to directly test against that method is adding unnecessary coupling with no additional benefit.

Comment: Just logged in again and noticed this. Nowadays I'm much more aware of how this works and I shouldn't mock the things I want coverage for. I'm defining mocks for modules using jest.mock now, so everything that is imported in the actual services contain the mocks I need. Works perfectly now. Thanks for the answer though.